shift arrows in a commutative diagram
I would like to write the following 
The problem is inthe middle
i wrote something like
\xymatrix{&LK_t=L'K_t\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\\
K_t\ar[dr]&&L\ar[dl]\\
&K}

(sorry but the previewer seems not accept xymatrix)
but the result in the real diagram is not satisfying. Angles are ugly and sides not parallel
I would like to have the two upper arrows beginning at the corner position (down-left the first "L" and right the "_t"
I read in the xypic manuel
 LD | RD | LU | RU offset to actual left/down, . . . corner
but there is no example given how to write
I tried different ways without succes.
Have someone a hint ?

It is hard to debug a fragment, please show a small complete document that demonstrates the issue.

With some visual formatting:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=dash]
\!\!K_{\mathrm{ur}}\,\,
\arrow[dddrr,start anchor={[xshift=-0.4em]south}] &&&&[-3em] \\[-3ex]
&&&& LK_{(t)}=L'K_{(t)}
  \arrow[ddll,start anchor={[xshift=-0.2em,yshift=1ex]south west}]
  \arrow[dd]
  \arrow[ddr,start anchor={south east}] \\
\\
&& K_{(t)} \arrow[dr]
&& L \arrow[dl,start anchor={[xshift=-0.2em]south west}]
& L' \arrow[ddl] \\
&&& K_L \arrow[dr] \\
&&&& K
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


